# getting compilation error when deploying to production gridmvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I installed gridmvc latest using nuget.  Things work fine in my local environment but when i deploy it to production, I get this error.  Please help.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly 'GridMvc, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File:    Line: 0

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean & compile in release before publishing to production and let me know if the same issue happens to you.
2. Please follow the guide below: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC
   and make sure you've done the same steps while configuring your environment and code.

I hope the above will address you issue.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  By doing some more research, it is working now.

Comment: Please mark it as solution so other and you will see it as answer.

Comment: I have posted answer to my own question above.

Comment: I see. it is in your decision if my solution led you to resolve the issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved now. All I had to do was, remove old referenced dll under References in this case (System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.0). Add new reference System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.1.  Click on the new referenced dll, in the properties windows set Copy to Local = True.

The in my project's root web.config file, change the following

FROM

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>


TO

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Then do clean and rebuild.  Then copy the new System.Web.Mvc (4.0.0.1) dll over to production.